# Access to a Struct inside an Union

Tags: c, struct, union

I'm working on an external libraries that has the following code in C:

```
struct ndpi_flow_struct {

....

  union {
    struct ndpi_flow_tcp_struct tcp;
    struct ndpi_flow_udp_struct udp;
  } l4;

  struct ndpi_id_struct *server_id;
  /* HTTP host or DNS query */
  u_char host_server_name[256];

  struct {
    ndpi_http_method method;
    char *url, *content_type;
    u_int8_t  num_request_headers, num_response_headers;
    u_int8_t  request_version; /* 0=1.0 and 1=1.1. Create an enum for this? */
    u_char response_status_code[5]; /* 200, 404, etc. */
  } http;

  union {
    /* the only fields useful for nDPI and ntopng */
    struct {
      u_int8_t num_queries, num_answers, reply_code;
      u_int16_t query_type, query_class, rsp_type;
    } dns;

    struct {
      u_int8_t request_code;
      u_int8_t version;
    } ntp;

    struct {
      char client_certificate[48], server_certificate[48];
    } ssl;

    struct {
      char client_signature[48], server_signature[48];
    } ssh;

    struct {
      char answer[96];
    } mdns;

    struct {
      char version[96];
    } ubntac2;

    struct {
      /* Via HTTP User-Agent */
      u_char detected_os[32];
      /* Via HTTP X-Forwarded-For */
      u_char nat_ip[24];
    } http;

    struct {
      /* Bittorrent hash */
      u_char hash[20];
    } bittorrent;

    struct {
      char fingerprint[48];
      char class_ident[48];
    } dhcp;
  } protos;
```

And when I do:

```
if(flow->ndpi_flow!=NULL && flow->ndpi_flow->detected_os!=NULL){
        snprintf(text[c], textSize, "%s", flow->ndpi_flow->detected_os);
```

The compiler (gcc 4.9.2) said:

error: ‘struct ndpi_flow_struct’ has no member named ‘detected_os’

I read on the web that C11 should be read the value of a struct field inside an union in this way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `flow->` So what is `flow`? What type is it? Please provide an [MCVE].

Comment: @EricPostpischil, write an answer, as your comment directly responds to the question the OP makes.

Answer (score 1):

`detected_os` is a member of `http`, which is a member of `protos`, so you need `flow->ndpi_flow->protos.http.detected_os`.